# How to add $ sign in textbox using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have created two text boxes which are txtAmount and txtAmountvalue. So for example, if the user enters 45.44 on text box then it should display it as 45.00 on both the text boxes.

Here is my Asp.net code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmountvalue" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's currently unclear what you're asking. For example, you're title has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. It takes the value of `txtAmount` and displays it in a formatted way in `txtAmountvalue`. The amount is rounded to the nearest integer so 44.49 becomes 44.00 and 44.51 becomes 45.00.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= txtAmount.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            var value = "$ " + Math.round(parseFloat($(this).val())).toFixed(2);
            $('#<%= txtAmountvalue.ClientID %>').val(value);
        } else {
            $('#<%= txtAmountvalue.ClientID %>').val("");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: One more question that I forgot to ask you VDWWD. If I delete the value from text box,The Nan value is appearing so could you please help me to get rid of that.

Comment: Updated my answer.